# CURL won't work over CURLOPT_PROXY server issue?

Tags: php, apache, curl, proxy, proxy-server

I am trying to use Luminati.oi proxy service to crawl URLs but there seems to be a problem with my server connecting to the proxy and utilizing the CURLOPT_PROXY functionality.

```
 $curl = curl_init('http://lumtest.com/myip.json'); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://example:24000');       
 curl_exec($curl);

 $result = curl_exec($curl); echo $result;

 echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl); 
 curl_close($curl);
```

I get no response at all from the target URL and the `curl_error()` function returns `Curl error: Failed to connect to exmaple port 24000: Connection refused` there are several variations on how to compose the CURL that Luminati.io provides, none seem to work.

If I remove the CURLOPT_PROXY option and just send the request direct from my server with no proxy, it works just fine and I get the correct response back from the target URL. So my server seems okay with CURL just not the proxy function.

The URL and port for the proxy server at luminati.io seem to work fine when using the desktop proxy manager. So the proxy service seems to work okay, the target URL is good and my server can use CURL with no problem, so it seems the issue is isolated around the `CURLOPT_PROXY` not working. The good people over at Luminati.io think there is some type of server setting or firewall in my Apache Linux server that wont allow the proxy connection to occur, I can't find this setting anywhere and Hostgator seems useless and apathetic when asked.

So I'm hoping someone can provide some greater insight into why CURLOPT_PROXY function wont work.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask Hostgator to give you access to port 22225. I think this is the correct port used by Luminati.

This is how you can contact Hostgator: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/open-new-ports

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer was extremely helpful in indicating the problem is with the outgoing connection. To make it extra perfect you could also add iptables instructions on enabling the outgoing port (it's good anyway though). The commands I ran as a result were: `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d zproxy.luminati.io --dport 22225 -j ACCEPT` and `service iptables restart` (this is on CentOS - the latter might be different for other OSes)

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. Unfortunately I gave up on the process when Hostgator let me know they had a policy against crawling on their servers any way. So I'm not able to confirm whether this solution worked or not, but If i revisit luminoti in the future -- I'll be happy to confirm your answer!